# Terraform modules source using both a ref for branch and tag

Tags: git, terraform, terraform-modules, git-refspec

I am trying to determine if it is possible to specify both a matching branch and a tag when declaring a module in terraforming.

In the [Terraform Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision) it notes that branch or tag can be used in the source for a module.

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=v1.2.0"
}
```

This works for specifying branch `ref=branch-name` or tag `ref=tag`, for my use case I wish to specify the branch as well as a tag simultaneously so that I can reference a module in a particular branch and at a specified version.

I would hope it would have worked something like this

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=refs/heads/branch-name?ref=refs/tags/v1.0.0"
}
```

This does not work, please tell me if this is possible and if so how.

Thank you ^_^

Comment: A tag is just a reference to a specific commit while a branch is a reference to a chain of commits (with the HEAD of that branch being the last commit). It doesn't make sense to say a tag of a branch because the tag could be pointing to any commit even if it's not on a branch (eg detached). Just pointing to the tag should be specific enough unless there's some specific issue you're having?

Comment: I see my misunderstanding. 
The problem I wish to solve is having a single repo that contains multiple modules where each module can be referenced while also specifying the exact version of the module.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing how you are structuring things but you can reference different directories in a repo rather than it just using the root of the repo with the [`//` separator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#modules-in-package-sub-directories) and then you can specify any refspec such as a branch, tag or even commit SHA directly to get the version you want. If you were planning on having different modules in different branches in a repo then I'd advise against that as development will be a bit of a nightmare.